# Routing through react router not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created some components. For the routing, I am using `react-router-dom`. My set up is as follows.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard.jsx';
import Login from './components/Login.jsx';
import Signup from './components/Signup.jsx';
import Application from './components/Application.jsx';

import "./assets/main.css"

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Application>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                <Route path="login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
            </Switch>
        </Application>
    </Router>, document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Here the my only '/' route is working, For `/login` and `/signup` I got `Cannot GET /signup`.

Please help me to come out from this. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: please , share the error from console

Comment: @NaveedAheer console is clean there is only `Cannot GET /signup`  on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `history={browserHistory}` in `<Router>`. Your code should look like:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
```

**Updated**

You should add following in your webpack.config.js;

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true
}
```

Comment: Did the same, but same issue persist

Comment: @Harish Can you please check your `webpack.config` file and check `devServer: { historyApiFallback: true}` is set ?